# Import / Export .ical in Google Calendar API

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I see there in the Web UI of Google Calendar that there is an option to download the .ical version of my calendar. I want to do this in my application I develop. I am looking over the Internet and in the documentation if there is something like that, but I can't find anything... Does the API provide this functionality? If yes, how can I start doing this?

Answer (score 6):

To make sure I understand your question, you wish to offer a "download as .ical" button on your web application, dynamically populated with the specific calendar event data from your application?

Think of an ical file (or more accurately, a .ics file) as just a string, but with a different Mime Type. The following describes the basics of the iCalendar format:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar

In ASP.NET, I'd recommend creating a handler (.ashx instead of .aspx) because it is more efficient if you don't need to serve a complete web page. In the handler, replace the ProcessRequest method with something like this (credit goes to http://webdevel.blogspot.com/2006/02/how-to-generate-icalendar-file-aspnetc.html)

```
private string DateFormat
{
    get { return "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ"; } // 20060215T092000Z
}

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
    DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMinutes(35);
    string organizer = "foo@bar.com";
    string location = "My House";
    string summary = "My Event";
    string description = "Please come to\\nMy House";

    context.Response.ContentType="text/calendar";
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=appointment.ics");

    context.Response.Write("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
    context.Response.Write("\nVERSION:2.0");
    context.Response.Write("\nMETHOD:PUBLISH");
    context.Response.Write("\nBEGIN:VEVENT");
    context.Response.Write("\nORGANIZER:MAILTO:" + organizer);
    context.Response.Write("\nDTSTART:" + startDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat));
    context.Response.Write("\nDTEND:" + endDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat));
    context.Response.Write("\nLOCATION:" + location);
    context.Response.Write("\nUID:" + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat) + "@mysite.com");
    context.Response.Write("\nDTSTAMP:" + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString(DateFormat));
    context.Response.Write("\nSUMMARY:" + summary);
    context.Response.Write("\nDESCRIPTION:" + description);
    context.Response.Write("\nPRIORITY:5");
    context.Response.Write("\nCLASS:PUBLIC");
    context.Response.Write("\nEND:VEVENT");
    context.Response.Write("\nEND:VCALENDAR");
    context.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! :-) 
But you see, I'm not doing it in ASP.NET and I'm not acquainted with it. It's a stand-alone application I'm developing in C#. In Google Calendar there is this button and when I clck it, I download the .ics file. I don't know where to get the .ics file address and how to implement it.... Can I use tha ebove code to it?

Thank you very much for your valuable help!

Comment: Oops, I saw C# and .NET in the tag cloud, and I jumped to ASP.NET. I think what you're wanting to do is discover the URL of the .ics file for a specific Google Calendar - and then use that URL within your application. Is that correct? If your calendar is listed as a public calendar, then it's just a matter of right-clicking on the green ICAL button and copying that URL. I suspect you're needing to access private calendars in a more dynamic way, though. In that case, you'll need to use the Google Calendar API for .NET: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html