# how to create ical calendar from google calendar in ios

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios7, google-calendar-api, icalendar

Hi friends,

I am working on calendar app. I want to export my google calendar and export as ics file via coding..

Is any one tried like this, please give some suggestion how can i create ical from google calendar..

I know how to export ical calendar via code..i want export .ical from google calendar ...

please suggest any good tutorial or link for complete this task..

i already looked these links but no one help me..

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605551/import-export-ical-in-google-calendar-api)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605551/import-export-ical-in-google-calendar-api)

Comment: I already implemented google authorization, i want to download my google calendar as a ical file..is anyone know how to do

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy using the CalDAV API as ics files is what it uses natively:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide

Comment: CalDav is deprecated... i found out the way and i successfully export my calendar as ical.. i used google calendar api and retrieve calendars and events and i exported it..

Comment: do you have any direct way to export google calendar as ical..what i did is retrieve calendar and events then i manually create ical file.. do you have any simple way? please share with us